# overlapping url codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

i am having a career page with apply now button

```
<a class="btn-system btn-medium" href="apply/<?php echo $job->id;?> " style="box-shadow:none !important;">Apply Now</a>
```

now i have mwentioned the route for this anachor tag as

```
$route['apply/(:any)']='welcome/apply/$1' ;
```

Now when i click to my header navigation which has the following link :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>


                            <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="careers">Career</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

It generates the link as base_url/apply/home thus not giving me the homepage or any other content

It is overlapping the link..Can neone help?

Comment: why you are putting the link in this way instead of using `base_url('home')` function. can you please post your errors or what actually it is overlapping..

Comment: Try using this $route['apply/(:num)']='welcome/apply/$1' ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend "link" with slash so it will be read from the root. Like

```
<a class="btn-system btn-medium" href="/apply/<?php echo $job->id;?> " style="box-shadow:none !important;">Apply Now</a>
```

I would put all of that in PHP with

```
<a class="btn-system btn-medium" href="<?php echo \"/apply/$job->id\";?> " style="box-shadow:none !important;">Apply Now</a>
```

Or as mentioned in comment by @RajJagani put it into `base_url()` function:

```
<a class="btn-system btn-medium" href="<?php echo base_url('apply/'.$job->id');?> " style="box-shadow:none !important;">Apply Now</a>
```

Comment: "link with slash is not doing any help"..instead i used site_url("home") in the href